# Combine RPI and Arduino

Tags: arduino, raspberry-pi, arduino-ide

I have a few questions about rpi and arduino.
 1. Is it possible to provide arduino and rpi two-way communication? (Sending data from the sensors to the Arduino and from arduino to RPI and processing information on RPI).
 2. Can i use sensors from Arduino on RPI?
 3. Can I programming RPI using C++ (such an as Arduino)?

Answer (score 2):

Yes, checkout the [ArduPi project](https://github.com/brice-morin/ArduPi). Serial communication (a USB cable) between the two is a fairly simple way to get started. It provides bi-directional communication between Raspberry and Arduino. And yes, you can compile C/C++ on the Raspberry Pi (but in most cases, you cannot directly reuse C/C++ for Arduino directly on the Pi, as it might use some special .h files not available on the Pi).

Answer (score 0):

Yes it can. Just use I2C Bus (or Two-Wire). By TWI You can easily communicate Rpi and Arduino.

Answer (score 0):

You can directly read the Arduino through the USB serial port. There is a Linux board I came across that you plug directly on top of your Arduino like a shield (It's called the [Rubix](http://smartrubix.com)) .

Answer (score 0):

Of course it is, Uart , I2C or SPI.

I highly recommand Uart.

1.The library GPIO has demo of Uart Communication.

2.You can use USB to connect the serial port.

you can follow this tutorial to make it run 
https://electrosome.com/uart-raspberry-pi-python/

Answer (score 0):

Yes you can communicate using I2C. There should be a wired connection between RPi and Arduino to communicate using I2C. If you wanna try wireless communication you can use ESP8266 13 arduino wifi shield.

https://www.tindie.com/products/doit/esp8266-esp-13-wifi-web-sever-shield-for-arduino/

Otherwise you can use a ESP8266 module replacing arduino and you can communicate bidirectionally using wifi.

Answer (score 0):

Most sensors that work with the Raspberry Pi, also work with Arduino and other boards like it.